# Will one-time usages of local variables be optimized at compile time?

Tags: java, c++, optimization, compiler-construction

```
double calcTaxAmount() {
    double price = getA() * getB() + getC();
    double taxRate = getD() + getE();
    return price * taxRate;
}
```

The function above calculates the amount of tax payment.

The price and the rate are calculated by calling some other functions.

I introduced two local variables price and taxRate to just improve code readability, so both will be used only once.
Will those kinds of "one-time" local variables be substituted and inlined at compile time with most modern compilers?

Comment: not sure but I think adding final may help. I would guess the compiler is clever enough to inlinethem

Comment: I would be a lot more afraid about using 5 getters. :-)

Comment: The code is written for presentation purpose. I don't code like this. I just needed a simple example to convey the intention of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, it depends on the compiler. Quite a few compilers are actually brain-dead when it comes to optimization, because they are dealing with dynamic languages which are complex enough that most optimizations are invalid and many others are only safe if very restrictive conditions are met (for instance, any function call could have nearly any effect). For instance, all Python implementations feature a compiler, but most of them only do very few peephole optimizations, which may not be sufficient to eliminate *all* overhead.

That said, if you're talking about statically typed languages (which your example hints at), then usually yes. Liveness analysis can detect the equivalence (you still need a storage location for, but the lifetime is the same), and any reasonably register allocator can avoid spilling the values needlessly.

That said, this is a really bad focus for optimization. If you *actually* want to make stuff faster, look at the final code and profile with realistic scenarios. And if you're going to micro-optimize, apply some common sense. Even assuming this function is a hotspot, the actual computation and getting the values may easily take 100x more time. A non-inlined function call takes pretty long compared to a stack store, and a cache miss is also pretty cost **at this level**.

Answer (score 4):

Generally yes.

Java only optimises code to native code after it has been called many time (10,000 time by default) If the method is not calls very much it won't make much difference in any case.

Even if it makes a difference of say 1 ns each, you would need to call this method 1 billion times to add a delay of 2 seconds. If its only 10 million times you are unlikely to notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the compiler can prove that they aren't aliased and modified externally, the compiler should be able to optimize them away (and I suspect that it can determine that here).

If you make them `const` I can't think of a compiler that couldn't optimize that.

All that said, this sounds like premature optimization and I wouldn't change the code even if it's fractionally slower because it adds to clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely on the compiler for C. Presumably yes for current compilers with proper optimization options turned on.

For Java it will *not* be optimized by the *compiler* (javac), but it may get optimized by the JIT when the code actually executes.

That beeing said, those local variables add very little overhead anyway. If the compiler decides to optimize the expressions to the equivalent of:

```
 return (getA() * getB() + getC()) * (getD() + getE());
```

It will still require some form of temporary storage (stack or register) to store the intermediate results of the subexpressions. So it shouldn't make much of a difference anyway.

I wouldn't worry about it and go with what offers better readability.

Comment: A JIT compiler is also a compiler.

Comment: @delnan While true, in the java ecosystem *the compiler* refers strictly to javac, not the JIT. (and this makes some sense because the Java language does not specify how its executed).

Comment: I don't know what the convention is in the Java ecosystem. However, while it is interesting that javac is less likely to optimize this, I'd say the distinction is not worth the confusion (read: I think you should say "the bytecode compiler" or just "javac").

Comment: @delnan Guess why there *is* the javac in brackets after *the compiler*?